# Write a program which gives an input from the user by asking 'Give me an input:'

Tags: python-3.x

Write a program which gets an input from the user by asking 'Give me an input:',and passes this string to 'silly_function' if the function returns without an error.simply print whatever it returned. However: if the function produces a ValueError,the program should instead print'I cannot use this value'; if the function produces a TypeError,the program should instead print 'Invalid input'

```
def silly_function(a):
    a = input('Give me an input')
    try:
        sily_function(a)
    except ValueError:
        print('I cannot see this value')[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Hello , welcome to SO, what is your question ?

Comment: Where are errors of my program?

Comment: Is ``silly_function != sily_function``?. If yes, then what is the code for sily function ?If not, then right now you are recursing infinitely. There is no way silly_function will output a Value_Error as there is nothing in it, and no termination whatsoever.

Comment: i forgot a 'l' in 'sily_function(a)' that should be silly_function(a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this together.

## Code Analysis

```
def silly_function(a):
    a = input('Give me an input')
```

this is fine, it will prompt the user for an input**

```
    try:
        silly_function(a)
```

**Why** do you need to call silly_function again ? I don't think that was the intended behavior ?

**Also** silly_function doesn't do anything that will terminate the recursion or generate an error , so this is bound to break.

```
    except ValueError:
        print('I cannot see this value')[enter image description here][1]
```

**Suppose** this is a typo, but `see != use`and you are only handling one error and not the other one.

## Suggestion

Let's right in pseudocode a bit of help

```
def error_handling_function(a):
    a = input('Give me an input')
    try:
        silly_function(a)
    except #input error here:
        #handle error here
    except #input error here:
        #handle error here

def silly_function(a):
    #write code that can break and generate the two error you are looking for
```